# how i can use setlocale (LC_ALL, "") with azerbaijan language? [c++]

Tags: c++

i want to use Azerbaijan language in my code, but i don't know how to use setlocale with my language, every time they just print symbols

i try to use setlocale

```
setlocale (LC_ALL, "aze");
setlocale (LC_ALL, "aze_AZE");
setlocale (LC_ALL, "az");
setlocale (LC_ALL, "az_AZ");
```

but there no right code :(

```
int main(){
setlocale(LC_ALL,"aze")
std::cout<<"Şənbə\n";
}
```

they always print "??nb?", how i can fix it ?

I use windows x64, outputting to CMD

Comment: On which operating system? Windows? Are you outputting to CMD? Powershell? Something else?

Comment: windows, yes im outputting to cmd